# How to make bash treat variables as strings using process substitution

Tags: bash, escaping

I have the statement:

```
A=$(echo "echo a") && bash -c "awk -v var=\"$A\" 'BEGIN {printf \"%20s\", var}'"
```

Which outputs:

```
          echo az
```

And I can't make this one-liner work:

```
A=$(echo "echo a") && bash -c "paste <(awk -v var="$A" 'BEGIN {printf \"%-200s\n\", var}') <(echo "BBBB") --delimiters ''"

a 'BEGIN {printf "%-200s\n", var}') <(echo BBBB) --delimiters '': -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
a 'BEGIN {printf "%-200s\n", var}') <(echo BBBB) --delimiters '': -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I presume this is because `"$A"` is not treated as a variable. Can someone explain this to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be working:

```
A=$(echo "echo a") && bash -c "paste <(awk -v var=\"$A\" 'BEGIN { printf \"%s\", var }') <(echo 'BBBB')"
```

But, I beg you, don't ever write anything like this. Its just plain gross, it makes people's eyes bleed. Please, use a real programming language like Ruby/Python/Perl if your shell scripts are becoming more complex then a list of commands and few "if" statements and/or are longer then can fit on one screen. Otherwise it would be so much FUN to debug and support these later or for someone else.

Comment: Good advice, I will implement a function that will explode the script after the unix epoch ends... kidding! Just one-liner for my learning.